# Remove two parts of url permanantly

Tags: http, web, nginx

I have redesigned a website and changed the url formats too. Now i need to change the old url to new one.

Here is my old url:

```
/solumina-G8/api/v1.0/user-avatar/avatarImage/currentUser
```

The new url would be:

```
/api/user-avatar/avatarImage/currentUser
```

I was successful remove just one of them using rewrite rule

```
rewrite ^/solumina-G8(.*)$ $1 permanent;
```

But I can't find how to remove both Solumina-g8 and v1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/solumina-G8/api/v1.0/(.*)$ /api/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Please add description around your code. It has appeared in low quality post.